# Run a different Django project's database script from a separate Django project's script

Tags: python, django

I have 2 completely separate databases that run in completely different Django projects. In one project, there is a script which analyzes the data and outputs the results as a CSV. In another project there is a script that takes that CSV and inputs its results into its database.

What I would like to do is to automate this process whereby when I run the analytics script and output the CSV, I then call the second project's database script and get it to import the new CSV data into its database.

Now the obvious thing to do would be to import, but since it's a django project this causes plenty of problems, mainly the settings files are missing, database import error, so on.

I tried running it as a sub process like so:

```
    subprocess.call("cd {0}\n python database2_import.py".format(project2_dir), shell=True)
```

but that has also not worked and is strongly recommended against.
I get an error stating that it could not import projects1 settings which is confusing because I am trying to run a project2 script.

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'project1.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named project1.settings
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Basically I would simply like to run the equivalent of "python database2_import.py" from project's_1 script.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that to make the subprocess method work, you need to specify the right environment. Since the subprocess is run from the project1's script, even though it is trying to run a project2's script, it is still using the environment from project 1.

Simply assign the proper environment as an argument to the subprocess.Popen.

```
import subprocess
my_env = os.environ
my_env["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "Project2.settings"
command = "cd {0}\n python python database2_import.py".format(project2_dir)
result = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, env=my_env)
```

That being said, I would still rather not use the subprocess method at all, so I'll hold on before marking this as the answer.